# remove theme tab on blocks for certain roles

Tags: 7, blocks, theming

I'd like to hide/remove theme block tabs for certain roles in drupal.
For example Administrator can edit both theme blocks, but other roles can edit only blocks that are available in their current theme.

Picture:
[image]

As you can see on picture, I'd like to hide **SEVEN** from other roles that are not **Administrator** ? Any ideas.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer led me to the correct solution.

Correct answer is this :

```
function remove_tab_for_non_admins_menu_alter(&$items) {
  if(isset($items['admin/structure/block/list/seven'])) {
    $items['admin/structure/block/list/seven']['access callback'] = 'remove_tab_for_non_admin_check_access';
  }
}

function remove_tab_for_non_admin_check_access() {
  global $user;
  return in_array('administrator', $user->roles);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function HOOK_menu_alter(&$items) {
  global $user;
  if(in_array('administrator', $user->roles) == FALSE && in_array('admin/structure/block/list/seven', array_keys($items)) == TRUE) {
    // This allows the path to still be registered but not displayed
    $items['admin/structure/block/list/seven']['type'] = MENU_CALLBACK;
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice. In case I decide not to change template file, is there a module alternative ? Thanks!

Comment: You could make a simple module and put that code in the module file. You would just replace HOOK with the module name.